# How to let cron decide the time to run laravel schedule daily?

Tags: laravel, cron

I don't want to set server cron to run every minute (* * * * *) so I set it to @daily

```
@daily usr/bin/php /home/dss/laravelAppDss/artisan schedule:run >> /home/dss/public_html/example.txt
```

This is my Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\SinkronDataDosen',
        '\App\Console\Commands\SinkronDataMahasiswa',
        '\App\Console\Commands\SinkronPotensiDO',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('SinkronDataDosen');
        $schedule->command('SinkronDataMahasiswa');
        $schedule->command('SinkronPotensiDO');
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't sync the data
This is the output example.txt

```
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' SinkronDataDosen > '/dev/null' 2>&1
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' SinkronDataMahasiswa > '/dev/null' 2>&1
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.0' 'artisan' SinkronPotensiDO > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

The commands worked if I run each command signature individually so there is nothing wrong with the commands

How do I solve it?

Comment: put some debug statements (like `Log::debug('...');`) in your commands. They should have been called. I cant tell whats happening inside them.

Comment: I think the documentation states that you should use (* * * * *) in your cron file and specify the commands schedule in your kernel file like ->daily()

Comment: @Flame I tried it in one of the commands, the laravel.log output is [2021-08-05 10:40:20] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException: Command "SinkronDataDosen" is not defined. in D:\Git_Undiksha\sistem-dss\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:584

Comment: @Aless55 does cron running every minute severely affect the server performance?

Comment: the cron job itself should not affect the performance in any way, it only depends on the task executed. But if these tasks are executed only on a daily basis you should not have any problems. 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: @Aless55 oh I see, thank you!

Comment: @daily - means it will run once at 00:00 So nothing will happen if it's not 00:00 I hope you realize that.

Comment: setting cronjob to @daily is this => 0 0 * * *